# Restful linking of existing resources

Tags: api, rest, restful-url

I don't think my setup is in any way unique, but I can't seem to find much information on the topic. I have a `User` entity. A user can have many `Roles`. The roles are pre-defined entities in the system and the client cannot create new roles. However a client can add or remove `Roles` from a `User`. I have a few ideas for how to implement linking a `Role` to a `User` this but I'm not sure which is the best option.

`GET /users/1/roles` returns a collection like:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name": "ACTIVE_USER"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name": "ADMIN"
  }
]
```

Here are the options I've considered so far

#### 1. roleId in body

`POST /users/1/roles`

```
{
  "roleId":1
}
```

#### 2. role id in url

`POST /users/1/roles/1`

#### 3. separate user-roles endpoint

`POST /user-roles`

```
{
    "userId":1,
    "roleId":1
}
```

#### 4. same format as `GET /roles` returns

`POST /user/1/roles`

```
{
  "id":1        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The roles are pre-defined entities in the system and the client cannot create new roles

I would advise against any of your options since they all do a POST request.

Remember the roles are predefined, you're not creating a new role so a POST request would be out of place.

Instead, since every user has a list of roles (may or may not be an empty list) I would simply do a PATCH request to update that list of roles with a new role. Remember PUT is create/replace, PATCH is "update"

A possible scenario could be that you can add and remove roles from a user. So I'd suggest you add an action parameter to the request body:

```
PATCH /users/1

[
  {"action": "add", "path": "/roles", "roleId": 1}
]
```

to add a role to a user. For removing you'd naturally replace `add` with `remove`.

See [this page](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) if you are curious where the usage of `{"action": "add", "path": "/roles", "roleId": 1}` comes from

Comment: I agree that POST seems wrong since it's not really creating a new resource (although it will result in a new db entry in the join table). However PATCH is in my opinion for updating a specific entity, in your first example it seems from the url that you're patching a collection. Adding an action to the request body would indeed make it clearer what was happening, but I'd like to do it without introducing extra data that an api user is unaware of - I like the idea that a client can use an api without needing api docs.

Comment: @mickadoo look at it this way: you're updating the user entry,  the update just so happens to involve updating a collection

Comment: However I may have made a mistake, I will revise my answer in the morning

Comment: It might be that PATCH is the right option. I've only ever used it to update a specific entity's properties until now but adding instructions for how the PATCH request should be handled seems to be what the author is suggesting in [this article](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/), but of course, would like to hear what you have to say in the morning

Comment: @mickadoo good find. That is basically what I meant to say, but backed better. I edited my answer accordingly